# Create Package To Install Programs

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, bash, scripts

Is there a way in Ubuntu to create a package or a script that when double clicked will install packages such as `Lamp` & `Joomla`?  Not sure if Ubuntu already has a pre-configured package to do this, or if I would need to write a bash file that would essentially run the `sudo apt-get install XXX`

What is the best route to do this?

Comment: Put all the commands you use to set this up manually inside a script, make it executable and execute it the next time you need it?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [docker](https://www.docker.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple really, you just said the answer yourself :)

Basicly do this

in terminal make a new file called command.sh (or something you like ending with .sh)

then type the following

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo apt-get install packages here -y
```

now I use LXDE for this piece but open alacarte and press new item, then just add the command `xterm -e "sh path/to/script.sh"`

then everytime you press the button you made, it opens a terminal and starts installing the stuff you want

and if you want to mix it up even more do this

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Enter the package names you wish to install and press enter: "
read names
sudo apt-get install $name -y
```

so that when you type the packages, it automaticly goes to download the files you want